# How to change the fonts and align minipage in center?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, minipage, alignment

I am writing a article using ACM conference template and I have added minipages in my two column article. But the minipages fonts are bigger and different. I need to make it similar to the article and allign it in center. Help will be much appreciated. thank you

```
\documentclass[sigconf,natbib=false]{acmart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{zlmtt}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=topline,numbers=left,label=Original Code,framesep=3mm]
class C {
public X x = new X();

public void f() {
...
}
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\par\vspace{3ex}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=topline,numbers=left,label=After Extract Local,framesep=3mm]
class c {
public X x = new X();

public void f(){
...
}
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}

\par\vspace{3ex}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=topline,numbers=left,label=After Extract Local,framesep=3mm]
class c {
public X x = new X();

public void f(){
...
}
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You specified the objective "align minipage in center" in the title of your posting,  but then went on to accept a solution that doens't perform any such centering. Was the centering objective not to be taken seriously after all?

Comment: Sorry mate. It should be align properly. Thank you so much. I am still wondering, Why can not I used \textbf{} in verbatim ?

Comment: The macro `\textbf` is not expanded in a verbatim setting. After all, the term "verbatim," which originates in Latin, means "word for word". Maybe you don't want 'verbatim' mode *per se*, but simply a monospaced font? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- To reduce the font size used in the `Verbatim` environments, you could load the `xlmtt` package with the option `scaled=0.9` (or some other factor smaller than `1`).
- To center the `minipage`s horizontally in the column, you could set their widths to `0.5\columnwidth` and encase them in a `center` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf,natbib=false,twocolumn]{acmart}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{zlmtt}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=topline,numbers=left,framesep=3mm, label=Original Code]
class C {
public X x = new X();

public void f() {
...
}
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=topline,numbers=left,framesep=3mm, label=After Extract Local]
class c {
public X x = new X();

public void f(){
...
}
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1\baselineskip}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=topline,numbers=left,framesep=3mm, label=After Extract Local]
class c {
public X x = new X();

public void f(){
...
}
}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}  

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry. Thank you for your effort, and it helped me. I am sorry, I forgot to give you vote up.

Comment: The other things, If I want to bold specific words, Why can not I use \textbf{} function.

Comment: @yaxier - In verbatim mode, the string `\textbf` is not perceived by LaTeX to be a macro that's to be explanded. I think that what you need to do at this point is to familiarize yourself with the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings). The entire purpose of the `listings` package is to simplify and streamline the typesetting of blocks of computer code. The use of a monospaced font is but one aspect of how computer code is typeset conventionally. Using `verbatim` mode -- which often uses a monospaced font -- is not really ideally suited for your typesetting needs.

Answer (score 3):

You need no `minipage`, using `Verbatim` suffices. If your aim is to avoid line numbers sticking out in the margin, use `xleftmargin`.

In order to make the verbatim text smaller, load `zlmtt` with a suitable `scale` option like in the example below.

It's better to use `\fvsetup` instead of repeating the setting each time, with the risk of forgetting some. The 15pt results from the 12pt separation between the text and the line numbers; I guessed the additional 3pt, but it seems to behave well in context.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,sigconf,natbib=false]{acmart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{zlmtt}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\fvset{
  frame=topline,
  numbers=left,
  framesep=3mm,
  xleftmargin=16pt,
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{Verbatim}[label=Original Code]
class C {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f() {
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[label=After Extract Local]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[label=After Extract Local]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much for helping me. What if I want to bold some text in verbatim, I guess I can not use \textbf{} function